# How to read from Msr (Magnetic Stripe Reader) directly in HID mode (not keyboard) without its OPOS driver or POS for .NET framework?

Tags: c#, usb, hardware, magnetic-cards

I have HP USB MINI MSR (Magnetic Stripe Reader) works by default in HID (Human Interface), and not in HID-KB (Keyboard mode).
I need some way to access the data read by the MSR directly without using any additional driver such as OPOS driver or POS for .NET framework!
Is there any native and clean way to do that (for example by accessing USB directly).

I need to do that in c#.

Comment: What you want probably isn't possible without the OPOS driver, unless you want to intercept the USB communications and reverse engineer the device's protocol. Even then, I don't think you can do it without p/Invoke, at least.